# Creating widgets inside nested for loop

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not able to access the outer for loop counter in inner for loop

Any idea on how to do this ?

````
class buildsubcategories extends StatelessWidget {
  List<cate.Categories> scat;

  buildsubcategories(this.scat);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int i = 0; i < scat.length; i++) Text(scat[i].categoryname),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (int j = 0; j < scat.length; j++)
              Text(scat[i].subcategory[j]['subcategoryname'].toString())
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```}


Expected Result : Able to access the variable i in the inner for loop
````

Comment: ```import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Categories {
  Categories(
      {@required this.categoryname,
      @required this.categoryImage,
      @required this.subcategory});
  String categoryname;
  String categoryImage;
  List<dynamic> subcategory;
  Categories.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> map) {
    this.categoryname = map['name'];
    this.categoryImage = map['imageurl'];
    this.subcategory = map['subcategory'];
  }
```}

Answer (score 8):

You don't have a nested loop here. Please see the comments I added below:

```
  children: <Widget>[
    // this creates scat.length many Text elements here
    for (int i = 0; i < scat.length; i++) Text(scat[i].categoryname),
    // there is only one column that comes after the scat.length many Text elements 
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // this creates scat.length many elements inside the Column
        for (int j = 0; j < scat.length; j++)
          Text(scat[i].subcategory[j]['subcategoryname'].toString())
      ],
    )
  ],
```

Here's how you can create categories in a nested loop:

```
  children: <Widget>[
    // note the ... spread operator that enables us to add two elements 
    for (int i = 0; i < scat.length; i++) ...[ 
      Text(scat[i].categoryname),
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // this creates scat.length many elements inside the Column
          for (int j = 0; j < scat.length; j++)
            Text(scat[i].subcategory[j]['subcategoryname'].toString())
        ],
      )
    ]
  ],
```

Note that to add two elements in each loop iteration we had to put the two into a list and unwrap it with the `...` spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the syntax you're using is proper as you're trying to create a for loop inside a return statement. Instead you can try this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> myList = List.generate(10, (index){
      var outerText = [Text("OuterText")];
      return Column(
        children: outerText..addAll(List.generate(10, (index){
          Text("Inner Text");
        })),
      );
    });
    return Column(
      children: myList
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's a new Dart feature: https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d#6c94

Comment: Wow. Thanks for bringing this into my attention! Saw your answer looks neat. Will start using that myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
 children: <Widget>[
// this creates scat.length many Text elements here
for (int i = 0; i < scat.length; i++) Text(scat[i].categoryname),
// there is only one column that comes after the scat.length many Text elements 
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    // this creates scat.length many elements inside the Column
    for (int j = 0; j < scat.length; j++)
      Text(scat[i].subcategory[j]['subcategoryname'].toString())
  ],
)
```

],